# Mongoose how I can return findOne data object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here the code:

```
var mongoos = require('./getMongoos.js');

var user = mongoos.addressFromMongoos(username[0]);

console.log(user); // i need the mongoos find here
```

getMongoos.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var userShema = new Schema({ 
    username: String
});
db = mongoose.createConnection('localhost/***');
var user = db.model('User', userShema);

exports.addressFromMongoos = function(username){

    user.find({username: username}, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
          callback(err, null);
        } else {
            console.log(user); //works
        }
    });

};
```

but i dont konw how to return the find user in the var user:

var user = mongoos.addressFromMongoos(username[0]);

Comment: Why? Why would you not return the data or otherwise use it from the callback? Your intention is not clear here and what you think you want to do is probably not what you really want. You could clarify this by editing your question to explain this.

Comment: i will only return the address from the user to another function

Comment: What I said before is that you are not being very clear in your intent. In all likelihood your other function should be called from or otherwise nested within the callback where the value is scoped. That is the point because outisde of that callback the value would not have yet returned.

Comment: anyone has a idee? how get the find in the variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly return an asynchronous result from a synchronous function.  You have to use callbacks instead:

```
exports.addressFromMongoos = function(username, callback){
    user.findOne({username: username}, callback);
};
```

calling it as:

```
mongoos.addressFromMongoos(username[0], function(err, user) {
    console.log(user);
});
```

Comment: but I need the user outsite the callback! 
mongoos.addressFromMongoos(username[0], function(err, user) {
    console.log(user); //this works
});

I need the user object here

Comment: @user3721702 You need to put whatever code that needs access to `user` inside the callback (or called from it).  This is how node.js async works.

Comment: there is no way to make a synchronous request?
or to call the data in a variable?